# How to avoid conflicts between jquery files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have managed to add a carousel slider and an image hover onto my site and I was looking to find out how i can ensure that there are no conflicts between them as there are both using jquery files.

The page itself can be viewed here:
http://s116169771.websitehome.co.uk/testsite/carousel/

What I am looking to find out is how i can separate the functions for both of these features as they are both using $ and I just want to ensure that there are no conflicts between the files so would like to ensure this is reflected in the code.

The problem is that I am not sure what changes I need to make to implement this so would appreciate it, if I could get some advice on how to split these up.

Btw the sources for these are the following:
http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/
Owl Carousel

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use one jQuery script for both purposes, if both require pure jQuery there should not be problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
// $k is now an alias to the jQuery function.

$k(document).ready(function() {
    $k( "div" ).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks sonu769 for that. If i needed to do the same for the hover feature, how would i define a noConflict for that? thanks once again btw for the tip, will try it out...

Answer (score -1):

Check out the following link to avoid the jQuery conflict.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: This is more a comment then an answer. Because your "answer" doesn't include any real answer (except 3rd party link that doesn't count, that it is not really yours).

Comment: And still, the link explains everything and comes up on google as the first result when you enter the question "How to avoid conflicts between jquery files". Why should someone copy all the information to the answer?